# Bootstrap component not working with react app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-5

I have created a **React Application** and copied **navbar** from **bootstrap component**. I also added cdn files at index.html file. Also changed changed class to className but still but when run I get error with failed to compile and cursor is placed on `data-toggle="colapse"`. upon removing this line it moves to next one. but its not working. .
[image: Error]

Comment: What does `button className = "xxx"` supposed to be? What is `data - bs - toggle = "xxx"` supposed to be? It's unclear what you're attempting to do. At the very least the JavaScript should be valid. In addition, you need to [post your code instead of linking to pictures of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because of attaching cdn at outside the body. I resolved this by placing cdn of CSS and JS at just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1):

working with bootstrap in react is not simple, it is easier to use React-bootstrap.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

you then just download the npm package and import the buttons and other options you want.

If you want to go about doing it this way, then you would need to use `<button className="bootstrapclass">hello</button>`

or specifically

```
<button className="btn btn-secondary">hello</button>
```

outside of that, there is no way to use bootstrap.

it is advisable that you share your code, so people can see what the mistake is.

Comment: my script is not working 
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
 and I have this comment also in my index.html, can you help me in enabling javascript in react using vs code

Comment: from what I can tell, that is an automatic response that the react, says when you have in chrome clicked the button to disable javascript. in the chrome devtools, (f12)